# Setting X and Y axis for both limits

Tags: vba, excel

I can't seem to get this code to work. I am getting a run-time error 13 'type mismatch'. As the code suggests I would like to set X and Y axis values from the ranges in Z6:Z9.

```
Sub Axis()
    Dim Cht As ChartObject
    Set Cht = Worksheets("Data Input & Summary").ChartObjects("Chart 2").Chart
    With Cht.Axes(xlCategory)
    .MaximumScale = .Range("Z7").Value
    .MinimumScale = .Range("Z6").Value
    End With
    With Cht.Axes(xlValue)
    .MaximumScale = .Range("Z9").Value
    .MinimumScale = .Range("Z8").Value
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: As a beginning - declare the `Cht` as a `Chart`. You would get a few lines under. :)

Comment: That gives me "Object doesn't support this property or method" error :(

Comment: I know :) But you have started to move down the code :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, you have about 3 errors in your code. 
This is how it should look like:

```
Sub AxisSomething()

    Dim Cht As ChartObject
    Set Cht = Worksheets(1).ChartObjects(1)

    With Cht.Chart.Axes(xlCategory)
        .MaximumScale = Worksheets(1).Range("Z7").Value
        .MinimumScale = Worksheets(1).Range("Z6").Value
    End With

    With Cht.Chart.Axes(xlValue)
        .MaximumScale = Worksheets(1).Range("Z9").Value
        .MinimumScale = Worksheets(1).Range("Z8").Value
    End With

End Sub
```

- You declare Cht as a ChartObject, but you set it to chart.
- If you declare it as a ChartObject, to get the `.Axes` you should refer to the `.Chart` of the Chart Object.
- Whenever you use `.`, it refers to the `with` above. And the `.Range` should not refer to the `Chart.Axes(xlCategory)`
- Last but not least - when you upload code to `StackOverflow`, it is a good idea to make it "reproductable". Thus, instad of `Worksheets("Data Input & Summary")` write `Worksheets(1)`. And then fix the name yourself.